# Powershell - Split strings of text file into chunks, then strip out unwanted info

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

Working with Active Directory export script. Currently, the script easily exports user objects from a given group into a .txt file as fully qualified names (ie. instead of reporting as "username", you get the ugly "CN=username,OU=foo,OU=bar,DC=foo,DC=bar").

My Powershell experience is novice at best. What I've gotten so far:

- load contents of text file
- split contents of text file at the ","
- write these contents into a second text file.
- resulting text file looks like this:

  ```
  "CN=username  
  OU=foo  
  OU=bar  
  DC=foo  
  DC=bar"
  ```

My goal:

- Save any resulting line of text that begins with "CN= (yes I'd like to keep that " at the beginning)
- Delete everything else
- Strip "CN= from the beginning of the resulting lines
- ***Note: usernames vary in length***

What I have so far:

```
$a = (Get-Content c:\test.txt | foreach-Object {$_.split(",,") })  
Out-File c:\results.txt -inputObject $a
```

I'm completely lost as to how to search text files for a pattern with a wildcard (ie. seach for any lines that contain "CN=* and keep those lines and those lines only) and then stick the results into a .txt.

Thank you so much for any and all guidance you might provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select-String` would allow that. It's kinda `grep` for PowerShell.

However, if I understand you correctly you can do that a bit easier with

```
$a = (Get-Content c:\test.txt | foreach-Object {$_.split(",,") }) -match '^CN='
```

The comparison operators can be applied to a list of objects and return only the matching items.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps also take a look at the [Quest AD cmdlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) and use that as your export script.  That way you can choose exactly which attributes you want without having to filter the output of a text file e.g.

```
Get-QADUser -Searchroot foo.bar/MyOu | Select Name, DisplayName, email
```

Comment: If you're using Windows Server 2008 R2, you also have access to the new AD PowerShell cmdlets - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Quest's script are indeed amazing, and I will look further into it.